# How to get linespacing of a TextView?

Tags: android, textview, fontmetrics

Is there any way to get the linespacing of a `TextView` in `Android`? I try to find `fontMetrics` of the `Paint` of the `TextView` and do like this:

```
tv1.getPaint().getFontMetrics(pfm);
float fontTop = pfm.top;
float fontBottom = pfm.bottom;
System.out.println("Line Space >> " + (fontBottom - fontTop));
```

But it seems that result is the same until I change font size of the `TextView`. So how can I get the linespacing of a `TextView`?

Answer (score 3):

Linespacing of `TextView` is

```
textView.getPaint().getFontSpacing() * textView.getLineSpacingMultiplier() + textView.getLineSpacingExtra();
```

Note `getLineSpacingMultiplier()` and `getLineSpacingExtra()` methods are available since API 16+.

Answer (score 1):

`getLineSpacingExtra ()`; Gets the line spacing extra space

```
tv1.getLineSpacingExtra ()
```

`textView.setLineSpacing()` or from xml you can use `android:lineSpacingExtra` for setting the extra space.

Answer (score 0):

```
    try {
        Field mSpacingAddField = TextView.class.getDeclaredField("mSpacingAdd");
        Field mSpacingMultField = TextView.class.getDeclaredField("mSpacingMult");
        mSpacingAddField.setAccessible(true);
        mSpacingMultField.setAccessible(true);
        mSpacingAdd = mSpacingAddField.getFloat(textView);
        mSpacingMult = mSpacingMultField.getFloat(textView);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```